# RVM Atomic gem not building native extension. RUBYOPT ERRROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler, atomic

I have install RVM and Ruby 1.9.3, and I get an error when I run bundle install.
The atomic gem causes an error, and before this, it was nokogiri. Please do help!

https://gist.github.com/karlcoelho/8268543

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

```
    /Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use path without space - it looks like bundler gets confused with the space.

Comment: That fixed it! I am the same guy who tweeted @rvm_io !

Comment: and I'm the same who was responding as rvm_io ;) accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: I'm getting the same error since upgrading to Ruby 2.1.0 installing the "thrift" gem. However, I don't have a space in my path. Might there be other reasons for this error?

Comment: yes there can be a lot of possible problems, open a new question with all the details